# Delete 1st and 3rd row of Df while keeping 2nd row as header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

started learning this stuff today so please forgive my ignorance.

My data is in csv and as described in the title, I would like to exclude the first and third row while keeping the second row as headers. The csv looks like this:

```
"Title"
Date, time, count, hours, average
"empty row"
```

The data set starts in the row following empty row.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `skiprows` parameter of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""Title
Date, time, count, hours, average

2018-01-01, 15:23, 16, 10, 5.5
2018-01-02, 16:33, 20, 5, 12.25
""")

# replace x with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(x, skiprows=[0, 2])

print(df)

         Date    time   count   hours   average
0  2018-01-01   15:23      16      10      5.50
1  2018-01-02   16:33      20       5     12.25
```

In fact, `skiprows=[0]` suffices as empty rows are excluded by default, i.e. default behavior is `skip_blank_lines=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `header=1` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for reading second row to columns only because empty rows are excluded by default:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Title
Date,time,count,hours,average

2015-01-01,25:02:10,10,20,15"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=1)

print (df)
         Date      time  count  hours  average
0  2015-01-01  25:02:10     10     20       15
```